# Cannot find formula of the progress bar (leveling system)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

please help me.  I can’t find the formula for the progress bar.  upon gaining experience, the bar begins to increase.

this is my formula.

`let progress = (point / tolvl) * 100`

I experimented and changed the value to a larger and a smaller one, but bar still the same.[image]

Comment: Please share a Minimal, Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It must depend on the length (in pixels) of the progress bar

Answer (score 1):

It's basic maths, and rule of three
Given the 100% (full bar) is 280 pixels, and I have `n` percentage, get the amount of `x` pixels:

```
x   280
- = ---
n   100
```

So if you have `65%`, you'd have this equation:

```
x     280
--- = ---
65    100
```

Now resolve `x`: `280 * 65 / 100` -> `182`